# Can't Unlock WSO2 Identity Server user using the REST request

Tags: docker, kubernetes, wso2, google-kubernetes-engine, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine. IS is configured to lock users when wrong password is entered 3 times. When an account is locked I use the given API in the IS documentation to unlock the user. Problem is half the time when I unlock the use it says user is unlocked in the server logs but user is not unlocked. When I checked from the UI it shows that user is locked and I have to unlock using the UI. This doesn't happen always but half of the time this happens.

Comment: Do you have a multi-node IS setup? if so, this might be due to caching. If you haven't enabled Hazelcast clustering  between these nodes, changes made by one node might not be available to the other nodes. (As nodes have their local caches and don't read from the database everytime.)
You can check if this is such a problem by having only one node up and running. If you can't reproduce the issue, then this is a clustering problem.

Comment: Also, what is the doc or API you are using to unlock the user?

Comment: @NipunThathsara I have checked this with one Node also got the same issue.

Comment: Can you answer the question farasath has asked above?

Comment: @farasath  this is the document https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/User+Account+Locking+and+Account+Disabling

Comment: That doc is for old versions of IS. Can u follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/User+Account+Locking+and+Account+Disabling?